# Thymelaf hasRole visible in JavaScript

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have a project with SpringBoot+Thymeleaf+jQuery. I would like to check a role of an authenticated user in my JavaScript. Based on a role, a new piece of thymeleaf will be rendered using jQuery. I've got this in HTML:

```
 <sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" var="hasRoleAdmin"></sec:authorize>
```

and then hasRoleAdmin variable is supposed to be visble in my JS, so I can do this:

```
function renderButton(){

 var btn="";

 if('${hasRoleAdmin}' == true){
       btn = "<button id='saveButton'>Save</button>";
 }else{
      btn = "<button id='viewButton'>View</button>";
 }

$("#root").append(btn);
```

}

My first thought was to render thymeleaf just like that with jQuery

```
btn = <span sec:authorize=hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')><button id='saveButton'>Save</button></span> 
$("#root").append(btn);
```

But either of this two worked. How to check spring security role in JavaScript? I'm not using inline JS, all soureces are separate files. Ther's an example how to do this is in JSP.

[springsecurity role check inside javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30775001/springsecurity-role-check-inside-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

To use thymeleaf inside your javascript you can encapsulate your expressions in `[[...]]`.

Now regarding your role issue. I believe you could do something like

```
if([[${#authorization.expression('hasRole("ROLE_WHATEVER")')}]]){
   ...
}
```

The expression should send the client true or false there. Also note that the syntax for #authorization.expression could depend on the version of thymeleaf libraries you are using; I can guarantee it works in thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4 version 3.0.4.RELEASE.